# ActionBar loses styling in the Multitasking Screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styling, material-design

How do i fix this? The issue is simple, when the app is open the styling is fine. However, when i pull up the multitasking menu, the action bar does not retain its styling (mainly color) and appears the color of the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Lolipop maybe.

You can set color when you pull up the multitasking menu.

Add this in your app style (style.xml)

```
<item name="colorPrimary">yourColor</item>
<item name="colorAccent">AccentColor</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">DarkColor</item>
```

Example :

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/favorite_color</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/favorite_color</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/favorite_dark_color</item>
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```